# Is there a way to combine Data Templates for a List View in .NET MAUI?

Tags: maui

My title might not be very accurate, but I am not sure how else to summarize it in one sentence. I am trying to create a reusable list view component that provides some static content and allows the implementer to provide the rest of the content.

[Here is an illustration of what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ou8c.png)

I do have working code, but scrolling is very slow and my solution just seems wrong. I am trying to find the proper way to solve this problem.

My current solution is essentially creating a DataTemplate inside of another DataTemplate.

**EDIT: [Here is a more detailed example of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjFZm.png)**

The Custom List View control:

```
<ListView
    x:Class="ReusableListView.CustomListView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:ReusableListView"
    x:Name="this">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto, Auto, *" RowDefinitions="*, *">
                    <Grid Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0">
                        <CheckBox HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                    <BoxView
                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        WidthRequest="1"
                        Color="LightGray" />
                    <Grid
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        BindableLayout.ItemTemplate="{Binding PartialTemplate, Source={x:Reference this}}"
                        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ., Converter={converter:DataTemplateItemSourceConverter}}" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code behind for the Custom List View control:

```
public partial class CustomListView : ListView
{
    public CustomListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static CustomListView()
    {
        PartialTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PartialTemplate), typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(CustomListView));
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty PartialTemplateProperty;

    public DataTemplate PartialTemplate
    {
        get => (DataTemplate)base.GetValue(PartialTemplateProperty);
        set => base.SetValue(PartialTemplateProperty, value);
    }
}
```

The converter for the Bindable Layout:

```
public class DataTemplateItemSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var result = new ObservableCollection<object>() { value };
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The Main Page where the list view is implemented:

```
<ContentPage
    x:Class="ReusableListView.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:lv="clr-namespace:ReusableListView"
    x:Name="this">
    <lv:CustomListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
        <lv:CustomListView.PartialTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Padding="4,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}Item Id: {0}">
                            <Binding Path="Id" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Label.Text>
                </Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </lv:CustomListView.PartialTemplate>
    </lv:CustomListView>
</ContentPage>
```

And the code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Data> Data { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
        Data = new(Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x => new Data() { Id = Guid.NewGuid() }));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Data));
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

I came to my current solution through many hours of trial and error and researching data templates and other controls. Is there a better way to implement the code I currently have?

Here is the full solution on GitHub: https://github.com/rsnate/ReusableListView/tree/main

Comment: I don't quite understand what special needs you have for implementing such a custom ListView. If you want to add new data on top of the original data, you just need to set the data type of the `ItemsSource` of listview to the following:  `public ObservableCollection<Data> Data { get; set; }` . The UI will refresh itself while adding new items to it.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT For example I want a checkbox in each row of every list view in my app, but I don't want to create and wire up the checkbox every time I add a new list view. I would like to be able to put that checkbox in my custom list view control so every future list view I create has the checkbox functionality without needing to write additional code.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can use [Data templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/datatemplate?view=net-maui-8.0) to achieve this.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I have updated my post with a more detailed example. Please see the edit at the top of my post or this picture https://ibb.co/zhzwhV1 .

I know I need to use a Data Template. If you look at my code I am using two data templates. My current solution is basically creating a Data Template inside of another Data Template. 

I want to know if there is a better way to solve this problem.